# Best Practice for Defining Collection Filters in a Spring Context File

Tags: java, spring, collections, guava, lambdaj

Whats the best practice for defining filters to apply to a collection of objects within a spring context file?

---

Say I have a Collection of Persons (`Collection<Person> people`). Each person has `age/name/sex/occupation/email` properties.

I need to create subgroups of these people, based on some standard & simple predicates. Example groupings may be:

1. `sex=Male`
2. `sex=Female && age>30 && occupation=IT`
3. `sex=Male && occupation=IT && email endsWith "aol.com"`

I can see a relatively straight forward route to doing this with Guava Predicates & `Collections2.filter()` by defining `Predicate(s)` in code, pulling them into collections in context file end injecting appropriate collection of Predicates where needed.

`JFilter` is a possible contender too, as you can define filters as Strings. LambdaJ seems to be the other popular option for filtering Collections in Java, but not obvious how to allow filtering logic to be driven from a Spring Context.

---

Is there a better way to go about this?

Note, I want to a avoid call to database each time, as I already have the collection of objects I care about in memory.

Comment: Do you mean these are currently being stored in the database tables? Or you want to use some other storage for this stuff to avoid databases.

Comment: So the objects I want to filter are held in a Collection of objects, not in a database.

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean by "better" here (as you already know about a couple of ways to do it)

Comment: Question I had was if there's a better/standard way of doing this that I've missed in my google-ing - I've edited the title to better reflect this.